# How to replace the last occurrence of a comma

Tags: javascript, bash, sed

I am writing a bash script that takes this file:

```
Chicago
Indianapolis
Denver
Miami
```

and turns it into this:

```
[
    'chicago',
    'indianapolis',
    'denver',
    'miami',
]
```

The problem is that this is a JavaScript array, and I need to remove the last comma from the last line. I tried keeping track of the last line and replacing it with sed like this:

```
lastline=1

echo [ > cities_array.txt

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    city=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/\l\1/')

    echo '    '$city',' >> cities_array.txt

    let lastline++
done < cities.txt

echo ] >> cities_array.txt

sed -e "$lastline"'s/,//' cities_array.txt > cities_array.txt
```

That last line writes absolutely nothing to the file, erasing everything. I also tried:

```
sed -e '"$lastline"s/,//' cities_array.txt > cities_array.txt
sed -e '$lastlines/,//' cities_array.txt > cities_array.txt
```

None of these work. How should I do this?

Comment: Does it work to just remove the second to last character?

Comment: I'm fine with simply removing the second to last character.

Comment: I'm sure you have reasons for using `bash`, but it really feels like using a language that supports `JSON` would be easier and cleaner.  Just read the file lines into an array, serialize the array to `JSON`, and save it back to a file.

Comment: +1 for model question, sample input, output, problem description, and ... gasp, ... code. You're almost there. Good luck.

Comment: @go-oleg you have a good point. Part of the reason for using bash is I'm just trying to get better at it. What language were you thinking of, anyway?

Comment: JavaScript (node.js) :-).  Or Python or Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you write:

```
sed ... file > file
```

bash interprets the `> file` and empties the file, before the `sed` even starts.

You can use

```
sed -i ... file
```

to do the edit "in-place"

---

By the way, you could make the whole thing a lot simpler:

```
{
  echo -n '['
  while read -r line && [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "'${line,,}'"; done | paste -sd,
  echo ']'
} < cities.txt > cities_array.txt
```

Although that will produce one long line instead of one city per line (all the same to javascript, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generating wrong syntax Javascript array and then trying to fix it I would suggest generating the right syntax Javascript using awk script like this:

```
awk 'NF>0{a[cnt++]=$1} END{print "["; for(i=0; i<length(a)-1; i++)       
      printf("\t\"%s\",\n", a[i]); printf("\t\"%s\"\n];\n", a[i])}' file
```

With extra whitespace:

```
awk '
    NF>0 { a[cnt++] = $1 } 
    END {
        print "["
        for(i=0; i<length(a)-1; i++)       
            printf("\t\"%s\",\n", a[i])
        printf("\t\"%s\"\n];\n", a[i])
    }
' file
```

Comment: Trust me, once you read little bit of awk it won't look confusing or daunting.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks so much for making it readable. Looks much better now.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: Only tricky thing is use of `\x27` for printing single quotes.

Comment: @anubhava: and what was wrong with `\'`? More readable and more general.

Comment: @rici, you cannot escape a single quote inside a single quoted string

Comment: @glennjackman: ah, right. It would have to be `'"'"'` which is not so readable, but still less coding-specific.

Comment: javascript strings can use single or double quotes, so there's that flexibility (that I take advantage of in my answer)

Comment: @glennjackman: that would be particularly useful if the city list included Val d'Or or Couer d'Alene.

Comment: @rici You can create a variable like `awk -v q="'"` and use that inside `awk`.

Comment: @JS웃: Yes, that's another possibility... doesn't solve the Val d'Or problem, though. Probably it would be better to use double-quoted javascript strings, as glennjackman suggests, since there is less likely to be a city name with a double-quote than an apostrophe.

Comment: @rici: Thanks for this meaningful discussion. I have changed single quote to double quote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

change your script to write this instead :

```
 [
   'chicago'
   ,'indianapolis'
   ,'denver'
   ,'miami'
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
# on line 1 insert the opening bracket
1i\
[
# on each line, replace the first char with whitespace, a quote and the lowercase char
s/./    "\l&/
# on each line, close the quote and append a comma
s/$/",/
# on the last line, remove the trailing comma
$s/,$//
# on the last line, append the closing bracket
$a\
]
' file
```

```
[
    "chicago",
    "indianapolis",
    "denver",
    "miami"
]
```

More compactly

```
sed -e '1i [' -e 's/./    "\l&/; s/$/",/; $s/,$//; $a ]' file
```